# Cookies aren't already loaded when app is mounted in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i found an issues while i was making my first frontend-backend project: when my app is loaded the cookie with the jwt isn't already loaded so the front end make a useless to the backend with no jwt. This make the jwt useless because of course i get a bad request and it doesn't auto-login.
Anyone know what is the problem or what i'm missing?

I make the request when the vue app is mounted in the store of my app. I tried to change the position of the request to when also the unsafe frame is loaded but nothing change.
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what happens. The description "Cookies aren't already loaded" is incorrect, the ones that are already set are available at any moment. In case you have race condition with loading jwt from the back end, it can be solved in several ways, basically race condition needs to be eliminated. The way it's done depends how things are done on your side